# A formula linked to cevians

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

In the `Concise Encyclopedia of Mathematics` of `Eric W. Weisstein`, in its **second** edition, I came across a formula noted in page $379$ (entry `Cevian`):
$$ s = \frac{b \sin \alpha '}{\sin(\gamma + \alpha ')}$$
Here is the corresponding image of the `Cevian` entry of the Encyclopedia:
[image]

No demonstration included; so, I tried to understand where it could come from, but I haven't been able to prove this formula.

Actually, I even don't understand where could I start to try to demonstrate it...

Could I have some indications, directions from you?

Much appreciated.

Comment: It's just sine rule on the smaller triangle (with $b$ and $s$ as sides).

Comment: O course! The upper angle in the lower triangle is $\pi - ( \alpha ' + \gamma)$. Thanks for pointing that out.